# GWT 2.7 starting a jetty 6?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gwt, jetty

I have a GWT maven project which suddenly stopped working (using GWT superdev mode). Seems there is some problem with the server. I noticed in the logs that jetty 6.1 is started. I did some research and apparently, GWT 2.7 normally uses jetty 8.

I did some investigation in my dependencies but did not find anything loading a jetty 6.

Any idea how to fix or debug this? Also tried GWT 2.8, resulting in the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AppEngine (at least the version you're using) uses Jetty 6.